# screen resolution(s)

Tags: iphone, mobile, width, screen-resolution, device

Am curious about the current recommendations for the width of website content.
Am currently working with a 700px wide area that contains important information whilst the container around this is 1060px which allows for the background image to create a larger visual area.

Things have changed since i made a website, mobile devices etc... I still know people who have  14 and 15" displays they use for their computer/ laptop.

I imagine am pretty much safe if i have the 700px width area for content, i understand the zoom feature is often used to read data on small devices, I do not currently own a phone with internet.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

See this article, it's one of the best things Iv'e read on the topic.

[Resolution Independent Mobile UI](http://www.sencha.com/blog/resolution-independent-mobile-ui)

Sencha is a well known mobile web framework, and that's on of their top articles.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using a fluid layout that works at any size. You'll probably want to set a max for screen, say 1260px and a min for mobile say 320px. Then use CSS conditionals for choosing between screen and mobile stylesheet.

Custom making the layout per your sites needs is usually the way to go, but there are many articles and frameworks out there to help you out;
[CSS Grid .net](http://cssgrid.net/), 
[The Perfect Fluid Layout](http://css-tricks.com/138-the-perfect-fluid-width-layout/)
etc.

Comment: the website is not intended for mobile use, but once i have a computer stylesheet complete i can make a style sheet for mobile devices. I just kept thinking is 700px to wide of an area. I think not, sites like facebook contain 3 columns which am sure would require more than 700px of screen space, regardless of liquid layout. i would rather have people on mobile apps scroll left to right than vertically. call me backwards but i felt horizontal scroll was nicer when tested a friends mobile internet device.

Comment: One thing which is really bugging me, am thinking about a layout/ design which has non seamless imagery for background styling, as the content is variable in vertical height, i must restrict the content due to image dimensions and pixelation, unless i set the image at a high res alternative i thought.  For example i would like a waving water image posing as a border around a div's content, but the styling for the water background depends on the content height. As you can tell am a little confused about fitting a design around variable content without loss of quality to the image.